# (CSS) I'm having trouble keeping the contents of a container centered

Tags: html, css

Sorry if this has been asked before. I'm very inexperienced with CSS. I tried looking through previous threads to see if I could solve this problem myself, but I've had no luck so far.

The website is http://greenemusiceducation.com/

The container right underneath the site's header is forcing all content (in this case a slider) to align to the right. In the 'site-inner' and 'wrap' classes (the classes that are listed right underneath the header in the sites source-code), I've tried editing the parameters but the changes don't seem to have any effect whatsoever. This container alignment issue is consistent across different pages for the site.

On mobile devices, the site loads fine and operates as expected. On Chrome, everything is right-aligned. On IE 11, the slider doesn't show up at all.

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: you have a bunch of unclosed tags https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fgreenemusiceducation.com%2Fgroup-lessons%2F

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: In your css, try removing `float: right` from `.content` and add `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Comment: Sorry about not posting relevant code, I'm a bit lost with what I should be posting. @MichaelCoker I tried your solution, but no dice. To make matters a little more complicated, I'm working on a site that I didn't put together initially. I'm suspecting that somewhere in the CSS, the previous site developer explicitly wrote that the container should behave that way for some reason.

Comment: @KoryHarris I made that change on one of the pages and it centered the main content. You need to post relevant code though. Odds are, if you do, you'll find what's causing the problem when you reproduce it here. Or at least then we actually have something we can solve. Just include the html and css needed to replicate the issue from one of your broken pages.

Comment: @MichaelCoker your solution ended up working for me. It turns out that I just forgot to clear Chrome's cache (embarrassing). But thanks again for your help!

Comment: @KoryHarris sweet! submitted as an answer if you're going to leave the question open and want to accept an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`.content` has `float: right;`. If you want to center it, remove the `float`, and use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to center it horizontally. Since the element has a defined width, that will center it horizontally. Here's a good resource on how to center things - https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score -1):

You can nest the style that is sliding to the right within a paragraph html heading with an inline style that sets the text for that to center. Even though there are other things beside text, it will still center the content of the container nested within it.

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><div="container></div></p>
```